# How to query Asana tasks based on modified timestamp

Tags: asana

You can use they query parameter `completed_since=now` to obtain all incomplete tasks within a project.

```
GET /api/1.0/projects/:projectID/tasks?completed_since=now
```

How can you also query based on the modified timestamp?

Comment: Could you please paste up the relevant parts rather than including a link?

Answer (score 0):

When [querying for tasks](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query) you can supply any combination of `workspace`(required for /tasks), `assignee`,`completed_since`, and `modified_since` to filter the results of your query.

Therefore, in order to filter the results by the modified timestamp simply supply the oldest timestamp you would like to include in the result set as the `modified_since` parameter.

```
GET /api/1.0/projects/:projectID/tasks?completed_since=now&modified_since=2015-10-26T01:02:03.004Z
```